# Camera2 api ZSL bug, onImageAvailable() not invoked

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2

I ran into a camera2 api error on my device.

I use ZSL, and after some photos, the camera doesn't work and stops capturing images. Investigations led me to the reason that the circular image buffer is empty.

Сircular image buffer is empty because the onImageAvailable() function is not invoking after that bug.

The strange thing is that everything is fixed only after rebooting.

For testing, I use [the ZSLDemo project](https://github.com/google/zsldemo) from Google.
Here is a snippet with onImageAvailable() function.

```
class CaptureImageAvailableListener(private val activity: MainActivity, internal var params: CameraParams) : ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener {

    override fun onImageAvailable(reader: ImageReader) {
        println("Try to add image into RingBuffer")
        val image: Image = reader.acquireNextImage()
        camViewModel.getZSLCoordinator().imageBuffer.add(image)

        if (null == params.debugResult || null == params.debugImage) {
            if (null != params.debugResult) {
                params.debugImage = image
                val tempPair = ZSLPair(image, params.debugResult!!)
                recaptureRequest(activity, params, tempPair)
            } else {
                params.debugImage = image
            }
        }

    }
}
```

UPD:
In the [logcat](https://pastebin.com/r2C82JXw) i found errors:

```
QCamera : <HAL><INFO> handleMetadataWithLock: 3911: Start of reporting error frame#=800,streamID=3, mCameraId: 0
mm-camera: <IFACE ><ERROR> 2473: iface_axi_handle_output_error: iface_axi_handle_output_error: OUTPUT_ERROR session_id 3 
mm-camera: <IFACE ><ERROR> 2291: iface_axi_fill_framedrop_struct_from_bufq_handle: Error! Uncleared Error mask 0x100 frame_id 6
QCamera : <HAL><INFO> handleMetadataWithLock: 3927: End of reporting error frame#=800, streamID=3 mCameraId: 0
Camera : <HAL><INFO> handleMetadataWithLock: 4078: Stream STATUS_ERROR frame_number=800,streamID=3 mCameraId: 0
QCamera : <HAL><INFO> handleMetadataWithLock: 4087: CAMERA3_BUFFER_STATUS_ERROR frame_number=800,buffer=0xf5496968 mCameraId: 0
Camera3-OutputStream: returnBufferCheckedLocked: A frame is dropped for stream 2 due to buffer error.
```

Comment: This is likely to be a device-specific bug, so to diagnose it, you'd need to look at the full system logcat at the least.

Comment: @EddyTalvala, I think you're right. But I don't see any system errors in the [logcat](https://pastebin.com/r2C82JXw)